# How do I alter text of an app interface after a button has been pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to alter the text of my app interface so that after the "submit" button has been pressed, "Question 1" turns to "Question 2" and the same for the check boxes (i.e. the answers change), this loop continues until Quesiton 4. Can I implement this from my java class? as I don't want to make a new interface for each question. Here is a screenshot of my app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B7kQ.jpg

The app is currently bare bones because I am just trying to learn how to do this.

The following is the xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_question_1" tools:context=".Question_1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Quesiton 1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Answer A"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:checked="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Answer B"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Answer C"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Answer D"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The following is the java code:

```
package com.example.user.frat_27th;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class Question_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question_1);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_question_1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply on clicking on the button, you can call a method that creates the appropriate question and in this method you set the texts of the textview and checkboxes and it will reflect in the UI immediately.

Something like this

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fillViewsForQuestion();
            currentQuestion++;
        }
    });

private void fillViewsForQuestion() {
    // Fill the text views texts and checkboxes text
    tv.setText("Question + " + currentQuestion);
    checkbox1.setText("Answer1");
    checkbox2.setText("Answer2");
    checkbox3.setText("Answer3");
    checkbox4.setText("Answer4");
}
```

currentQuestion should be class member along with the other views in order not to initialize them each time you proceed to next question

Hope this helps!